# Find and Replace in Notepad++ - Regular Expression

Tags: regex, replace

I want someone who can help me with notepad++ search and replace.

There is a text with info like this and i want to remove the space which in numbers and replace it with blank.

```
|customer:5188680107|country us|First Name:Candice|Last Name:Astley|DOB:16-04-1981|Adress 1: 12 Linda drv|
|customer:7258288 11|country us|First Name:mego|Last Name:Astley|DOB:16-04-1981|Adress 1: 12 Linda drv|
|customer:2 22222222|country us|First Name:pat|Last Name:bla|DOB:16-04-1980|Adress 1: 12 Linda drv|
|customer:333333 010|country us|First Name:delo|Last Name:blabla|DOB:16-04-1912|Adress 1: 12 Linda drv|
```

I want it to be like this :

```
|customer:333333010|country ..
```

Comment: i have much info which have space ! i want just remove space which in |customer:HERE|

Comment: Please read the [faq].

Comment: "What have you tried, what didn't work? –  Purrfection"   i don't try because i don't know the correct way.

Comment: Purrfection…!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

Find what: `(\d)\s(\d)`
Replace with: `\1\2`

This has been tested and it works.

Good luck!

Image prior to doing all the replacements:

[image]

Image after doing all the replacements:

[image]

**EDIT**

This seems to suit your needs better:

[image]

Comment: if you are talking about this one , i already try it and not worked.

Comment: I just tested this one with your own text and it worked perfectly. Did you remember to set the radio button to Regular Expression?

Comment: yes i did! and when i do search it give me that can't find it!

Comment: Check that your buttons and settings are all the same as in the image I just added. I have tried it several times now and it worked every time.

Comment: yes its worked perfect now , but the problem its REPLACE every info that has SPACE , i want remove just SPACE which in |customer:333 333 010| when i try your code its replace even the SPACE which in Adress 1: 12 3 Linda drv|

Comment: You have no value that says 1: 12 3 Linda drv! You only have 1: 12 Linda drv. 

If it's removing spaces between digits that you don't want to replace, use this in the Find What: customer:(\d+)\s(\d*)

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer. It shows a better way of doing it. *NOTE* It is similar to Peter Alfvin's, but not exactly the same. If you choose this as the accepted answer, please at least vote his up.

Comment: I am glad to hear it's working! Make sure to thank the other guys as well. It was difficult to figure out exactly what was happening, since the text you sent us was different from the text you were working on. They worked hard and provided some good answers too.

Comment: i want vote but its asking me for '"Vote Up requires 15 reputatio'"

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of that. I'll vote up for you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Windows, so I can't test on Notepad++, but the following should work:

```
Search: |customer:(\d*) (\d*)|
Replace: |customer:\1\2|
```

provided that you only have one space per entry.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html to read about backreferences, which are used in the above.

Comment: i try it and not worked. i did search and replace, but not work

Comment: probably will need to escape the `\\`

Comment: Invalid regular expression , i think its not correct , but its show me invalid regular expression.

Comment: @user2658187 Try to use the proposed expressions but without "|".

Comment: i try it , but its replace all the text , i need to replace just SPACE which in |customer:333333 010|

Comment: No, my most recent answer. not my first, I deleted that one because I misunderstood your question. Please see the latest one here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20696392/2990189

Comment: @user2658187 How about simply `Find: (?=\d*) (?=\d*\|)` and `Replace: Nothing`, this replaces the space between the digits in the customer field. See [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/tV4vD7)

Comment: not work too ! i need replace just SPACE which in |customer:HERE|

Comment: Your data is different then you say or you don't have the `Regular expression` option checked on your screen because this works fine when I tested.

Comment: I agree with @hwnd, mine works just fine as well. You must have something set differently. Perhaps you left a space in the "Find what" box?

Comment: @hwnd,its work but i want change just data which in |customer:HERE|, when i try your code its changing all the place which have space btc numbers.

Comment: thank you all of you guys for the help ! I'm sorry for taking your time , thank you again !